# Is there a desktop environment that is almost solely the terminal

Tags: desktop-environments, 20.10

I'm looking for something that instead of a regular desktop it is only the terminal. But I do want to be able to launch applications from it and be able to manipulate those windows. I was hoping there was a DE like this or perhaps a WM I could use in conjunction with something else. I haven't been able to find anything yet. Any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to install Firefox on Ubuntu with no desktop enviroment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1150493/816190)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are looking for. If, in regular Ubuntu, you install `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` and `gnome-shell-extension-autohidetopbar`, you will get close provided you launch "Extensions", disable the "Desktop Icons" and "Ubuntu Dock" extensions, and enable the "Auto Hide Topbar" extension. When you start up with that configuration, you will be sitting before an empty desktop only showing your wallpaper. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, you can launch a terminal. You can launch any application from there. Or you press "Super" to launch applications or to manage your windows.

If you cannot disable the extensions this way (it is possible in Ubuntu 20.10 but perhaps not in Ubuntu 20.04), then install `gnome-session` for a vanilla Gnome Shell desktop. Then, you only need to install the "Auto Hide Topbar" extension.

You could also start from other desktop environments like "XFCE", "Plasma" etc. and remove all chrome and menus you do not want to use.

You can also go for just a window manager. "Openbox" is a tiling window manager, and there is a range of tiling window managers like "i3", "Xmonad", "bspwm" to name a few. However, these require some learning curve to set them up.

Finally, you could work like Richard Stallman does: start up to a terminal and use console programs (emacs does almost everything) and only launch Xorg in case you need to work with a graphical program like Gimp.

The floor is yours. This is linux.