# How can I open a gui application from the tty

Tags: command-line

I would like to run a GUI application like Firefox from the TTY and I have been unable to find any way to do so. Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean you think it wouldn't work for you?   I just tried it through those instructions and it worked fine.  Did you try anything at all?  Please edit your question and add more details of maybe why you think it won't work or add in anything that you have tried so far.  Thank you!

Comment: @Terrance I figured out I meant the TTY not the console. I don't know if it is necessarily possible at all

Comment: I don't understand what you mean that if it is necessarily possible at all?  If you're trying to run it from a desktop you will have to kill whatever the DM is, whether it is LightDM, GDM, etc.  You haven't said anything about what version of Ubuntu you want to use, etc.  When I tested it on mine, I ran it from Ctrl+Alt+F3 to kill GDM and Ctrl+Alt+F4 to launch Firefox exactly as those instructions show and it came right up, even though it was only 640x480, but it worked.  So, how do you know it won't work if you don't try it?

Comment: I didn't have xterm installed. I had already tried it all multiple times before I asked the question. I probably should've been able to notice it sooner. C'est la vie I suppose. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need xterm.  It is X11 (xorg) that does it.  Did you read the instructions carefully?

Comment: Perhaps related: [Is it possible to install Firefox on Ubuntu with no desktop enviroment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1150493/250300)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the DISPLAY variable. In a default xserver configuration this should be :0.

So on your tty try this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 firefox
```

To find out what that variable contains for your desktop (if above doesn't work) start a terminal on your desktop and run

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

And use the output on in the first command